# Reserving a set of ids in autoincremented column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with autoincremented columnd 'id'.
The current AUTO_INCREMENT value is 99. So the next element, inserted to this table will have id=99.

I need to add a 1000 rows, forcing their ids to 2000-3000, and then reserve these values to not mess with others. I mean, after inserting these rows, I would like to return AUTO_INCREMENT value to 99, so that next row will have value 99, after that 100 and so on.
Regular ids will not raise higher than 1000, so I want them to get incremented in normal way.

I know it looks not so elegant, but it would make things a lot easier for a particular task.

Is is possible at all?

Comment: Never mess with the auto incremented IDs. Better lokk for another way. Why do you want to do that anyway?

Comment: @juergen_d I am actually using another way at the moment. But it is kind of complicated and requires a lot more additional queries to DB. So I thought may be it was possible to use another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to add a 1000 rows, forcing their ids

## Nope, You Don't

Autoincrement field is not what you think. It's unique identifier that's have no particular meaning at all. So - just leave it alone. If you want some sort of meaningful identifier - add another field and play with it whatever way you want.

> Is is possible at all?

Fortunately - no.

Comment: It is possible. The auto-increment value can be changed in MySQL. It is just not recommended.

Comment: @juergen d I tried to change it to a lower value, that is not sererved by any row in PHPMyadmin under 'operations' tab, but it is automatically changed to 'highest ID+1'

Comment: @juergend it is not possible the way he needs it, if you care to read the question